# Configure multiple IPs with different gateways in Netplan on Ubuntu 22

Tags: netplan

I run a cloud server and assigned two public IPs to it but have struggle to make it working with netplan, here is my configuration:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
        - 1.2.3.4/22
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 1.2.0.1
          table: 101
      routing-policy:
        - from: 1.2.3.4
          table: 101
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 4.2.2.4
          - 8.8.8.8
    eth1:
      addresses:
        - 5.6.7.8/22
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 5.6.4.1
          table: 102
      routing-policy:
        - from: 5.6.7.8
          table: 102
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 4.2.2.4
          - 8.8.8.8
```

When I apply the above configuration and run `route -n` I get this routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
1.2.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
5.6.4.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Since there is no default route applied, the server has no internet connection (although SSH works).

How should I configure two public IPs on a server that can send and receive packets on their own route?